# AWS Pinpoint Transactional Emails : How to include an unsubscribe link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, transactions, sdk

I am trying to understand what causes an "_email.unsubscribe " event in AWS Pinpoint for sending Transactional Emails. I want to add a link with which users can click to unsubscribe. I am using JAVA SDK 2.X.   The developer guide was not very helpful. I'd appreciate if someone can post a sample code or an approach that would help .

Answer (score 2):

from AWS documentation:

> Emails unsubscribed – The number of messages that prompted the
> recipient to unsubscribe. Note In order for Amazon Pinpoint to count
> an unsubscribe event, the unsubscribe link in the email has to contain
> a special link tag (a tag called unsubscribeLinkTag, as in the
> following example:

```
 <a ses:tags="unsubscribeLinkTag:click;" href="http://www.example.com/unsubscribe">
```

> Only links that contain this tag are counted as unsubscribes.

basically, it just generate an unsubscribe event to kinesis